# JList showing empty lines in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a following array:

```
static String[] nameData = new String[100];
```

And a `JList`, with displays the array's contents:

```
rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
final JList list = new JList(nameData);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
listScroller.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
rightPanel.add(listScroller);
```

But when for example only first slot in the array are filled and rest are with the value null, `JList` still displays them as an empty line and lets you select it (I have added an image below).

[image: 7th element in array]

This is how a 7th element in array would be selected, although I would like the `JList` only to display elements that have a value besides null.

Comment: are you sure about it **list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to display null/empty values, you can either create another String by removing null entries or the more preferable option, use a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)

**Create another String**

```
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<nameData.length;i++){
    if(nameData[i]==null) break;   // count number of elements
}
String[] myString = new String[i];  // declare string
for(i=0;i<myString.length;i++){
    myString[i] = nameData[i];      // copy
}
// Create JList
final JList list = new JList(nameData);
```

Or

**Use DefaultListModel**

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
for(int i=0;i<nameData.length;i++){
    if(nameData[i]==null) break;
    model.addElement(nameData[i]);   // build defaultlistmodel
}
final JList list = new JList();
list.setModel(model);
```

Comment: 1) I think he need `continue;` instead of `break;`. 2) First method is't working. You can catch `Array Index Out of Bounds Exception`.

Comment: Why do u think we need break instead of continue? What error do you see in the first method? Sorry, i cant see where we can get an exception. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Because you use `nameData.length` instead of `myString.length`.  `Continue` because values mayBe in different indexes

Comment: Thanks! made the edit, about mixed null values, the only reason the OP has null values is that because he has less than n elements where n is the length of the array. I guess its not possible to have null values at random positions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read tutorial for [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

You add `new String[100]` to your list, because of it has 100 values. You can filter your array before adding to `JList` or ListModel for getting only notNull and notEmpty values.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use Array of 100 null elements, you can use Vector instead